# PHP/Apache TCP/IP sockets on AWS EC2 instances behind Application load balancer

Tags: apache, sockets, amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

I have deployed my PHP project on multi instance AWS setup. These instances are behind the Amazon's Application load balancer.

I have successfully setup security groups and allowed port e.g, 7000

**Problem**

This properly established connection with my server but when I try to write on this port I get **400 bad request** response from load balancer.

Here is the response I am getting

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Mon, 05 Jun 2017 08:48:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 138
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I try to establish connection directly with an instance with its public IP it works.

I feel I am missing something at load balancer end.

Please guide.

Comment: A 400 error is a strictly HTTP response which indicates that you're forwarding to/via an HTTP port instead of a TCP port.

Comment: @apokryfos how can I check that? If I write directly to instance it works.

Comment: In the classic load balancer there's a way to indicate what protocol the forwarded port should use, I'm sure the application load balancer should have a similar setting (though I don't know where it would be as  I only have experience with the classic load balancer). It should be at the same place you've set-up the port forwarding.

Comment: Yes, in Application load balancer there is a setting to forward TCP on port to instances which I have already did. when run server script to listen on port and then establish a connection on that port with telnet on command line it works and when I type something to write on port I get 400 bad request error.

Comment: You are mistaken. It is not possible for an ALB to be configured to forward raw TCP. [Unlike a classic load balancer, an application load balancer cannot have non-HTTP TCP or SSL/TLS listeners](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-applicationloadbalancer.html).  You cannot use ALB in non-HTTP configurations.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - thanks for your comment. then what ALB supports on TCP?